# Header from top equivelant in LibreOffice

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice

I try to follow some formation instructions for a few documents I need to deliver to a customer. The documentation instructions are set for Office 2007 but I need to write the documentation in LibreOffice (deliverable will be PDF, so no issue).

The page instructions although seems simple, though, are difficult to follow.
I have no problem with those:

```
Margins: 2cm (Left, Right, Top, Bottom)
Gutter: 0,5cm (Left)
```

But, next, is the instructions that I found no relevant options in LibreOffice:

```
Header from top: 1,25cm, 
Footer from Bottom: 1,25cm
```

So, the question is simple: How do I set the Header/footer spacing from page boundaries in LO?

Comment: Hi, what about using a custom paragraph style for header/footer?

Comment: I don't see how that will help...